# Calculating f-stop with given focal length and desired depth of field?

Tags: optics, lenses

I have a varifocal zoom lens set to a desired focal length and at known distance from the subject. I also have a desired depth of field.

Given this information, can I calculate a theoretical f-number to achieve the desired depth of field?

If so, how would this be done?

Is the exposure and sensor size also required to make this calculation?

Comment: Many tools available online. See for example http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/technical/depth_of_field_calculator.do

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible using all of:

1) The thin lens graphing formula

2) The small angle approximation: $sin(x)$ ~ $x$ for small $x$.

3) The circle of least confusion.

**Hovever** a better approach might be to graph depth of field [ using whatever accuracy or lens definition criteria you are interested in ]

For specific distances and *f-stops* using your particular lens and sensor size.  Then interpolate between these values.